# Do I Have to Change My Seed after Multiple Transactions?

Tags: transaction, wallet, security, seed

Is it recommended to change the *seed* and transfer the funds after creating a higher, specific amount of Receive addresses and doing multiple (20+), completed transactions (no double-spending of course)?

Or is it safe to use one and the same *seed* for many transactions as long as you do not double spend and properly follow the wallet instructions.

Comment: There seems to be a misconception about seeds and addresses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between a private key and a seed?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/584/whats-the-difference-between-a-private-key-and-a-seed)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's safe to keep your seed. Even if you [**double-spend** or **reuse your address**](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/581/10), your seed doesn't get exposed, only the private key of one address of your seed is partially revealed. You can generate an **infinite** amount of addresses with one seed.

- [What's the difference between a private key and a seed?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/584/10)
- [What is the difference between "double-spending" and "address-reuse"?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/581/10)

#### But there is one reason, why you should maybe change your seed after every snapshot:

After a snapshot, a stateless wallet (like the current official IOTA Wallet 2.5.6) does not know which addresses it already used and which it didn't. So you could accidently [reuse an address](https://iota.stackexchange.com/q/581/10).